# ASP.NET MVC get specific record from view model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Say I have a view model which includes fields for:

```
UserId, FirstName, LastName, City, State, Zip
```

When the page loads it displays a table of users, but only the FirstName, LastName and a "Details" button. If the button is clicked, it displays a pop-up window that shows all fields in the view model.

I'm unsure how to accomplish this. If I tie the button to the **UserId**, can I then find the specific record in the view model to display in the pop-up? Or do I need a POST to the controller?

**UPDATE WITH CODE**

I'm posting the relevant code snippets below. When I click on the Details link I would like the user details to show in a bootstrap popup modal window created in a partial view. But it is opening a new browser window and showing just a JSON string?

**From Main View**

```
<td><a href="@Url.Action("AdminGetUserDetails", "Admin", new { Id = user.Id })"> Details</a></td>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult AdminGetUserDetails(string Id)
    {
        AdminUserDetails userDetails = new AdminUserDetails();
        userDetails = _adminRepository.AdminGetUserDetails(Id);

        return Json(userDetails, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**jQuery**

```
function getAdminUserDetails(userId) {
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("AdminGetUserDetails", "Admin")',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: { id: id },
    success: function (userDetails) {
        $('#UserId').val(userDetails.UserId);
        $('#UserName').val(userDetails.FirstName);
        $('#Email').val(userDetails.Email);
        $('#Avatar').val(userDetails.Avatar);
        $('#City').val(userDetails.City);
        $('#State').val(userDetails.State);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: When you click on the detail button pass the unique id for this record( may be the UserId) and using that query the user record again to get the full details and then you can show that wherever you want (modal dialog/ same page etc). You can use twitter bootstrap modal dialog /jQuery.

Comment: That was my first idea, but I'm unsure of how that's done. Is it a Linq query in the view?

Comment: No, it's a different controller action.  Split you view model from the grid viewmodel and a detail viewmodel.  When you click the details grid button you call the details controller action using Javascript  returning a partial view with the details view model.

Comment: You can tie your UserId to button, make ajax POST to server, query it with linq or lambda or else, then post it back and display results in some modal view (eg. Bootstrap Modal). Take a look at datatable.js for some events on clicking rows, buttons ect. You can make Web.Api and there you can handle some logic.

Comment: So it seems that I should have two models, a limited grid view model and a full detailed model. But it will basically required two controllers and two calls to the database?